# What's the recommended way of creating View Controllers for SubViews?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, subview

I've read that a UIViewController is really supposed to manage the root view of your view's hierarchy, and as a general practice, while you can use it for Navigation controllers or split-view controllers, you yourself aren't supposed to use the view it exposes as a subview of another view that's also managed by a UICiewController, creating a nested ViewController hierarchy.

In short, you're not supposed to use a UIViewController for Subviews.

Or at least that's the way it originally was.

However, I vaguely remember this has changed in the later SDKs and it's now supported, but I can't remember (or find) if there's a new UIViewController-like class or subclass for this purpose, or if Apple enhanced the standard UIViewController for that role.

Our use-case is a UICollectionView subclass that isn't full-screen, but rather a smaller part of another view.  There may even be multiple instances of it on the same screen.  Since UICollectionViewController already conforms to UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource, we figured we'd just start using that.  Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using container views?  They are like view controllers all by themselves.  This is an addition in newer Xcode versions.  You could drop a collection view right into one.